# Problems with Custom DataGridViewRowCollection

Tags: vb.net, thread-safety, custom-controls, vb.net-2010

I am currently working on a multi thread project. The idea is to implement the threat security into my own custom controls. Now I want to override properties of the `DataGridViewRowCollection` such as the `DataGridView.Rows.Add()` and `DataGridView.Rows.Remove(row as DataGridViewRow)` with my code for the threat security.

My idea was to use an own `DataGridViewRowCollection XRowCollection` instead of the basic `DataGridViewRowCollection`. When I try to override the `Rows` property, I get the compiler message:

> "Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Rows As XRowCollection" and
>   "Public Shadows Property Rows As
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection" cannot overload each
>   other because they differ only by return types

I would be thankful for any solution or any alternate ideas to implement the threat secure code directly in my cutsom contorl.

```
Public Class XDataGridView
  Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

  Private _Rows As XRowCollection
  Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Rows As XRowCollection
    Get
        If _Rows Is Nothing Then
            _Rows = New NoxRowCollection(Me)
        End If
        Return _Rows
    End Get
  End Property
End Class

Public Class XRowCollection
  Inherits DataGridViewRowCollection

  Public Sub New(dataGridView As XDataGridView)
    MyBase.New(CType(dataGridView, DataGridView))
  End Sub

  Private Delegate Sub RowsRemoveCallback(DataGridViewRow As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow)
  Public Shadows Sub Remove(DataGridViewRow As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow)
    If MyBase.DataGridView.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New RowsRemoveCallback(AddressOf Remove)
        MyBase.DataGridView.Invoke(d, New Object() {DataGridViewRow})
    Else
        Me.DataGridView.Rows.Remove(DataGridViewRow)
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: When you override something, it needs to return the same thing. I think you are trying to solve your problem the wrong way. Why do you need to call Invoke in the Remove ?

Comment: Well, the Invoke in the Remove needs to be called, because there are other threats adding and removing rows to the DataGridView the same time, so the Remove has to be threat secure. Any idea for another way ?

Comment: Invoke isn't meant to make something thread safe. You'll have to use [synclock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/synclock-statement).